# mod-rewrite Rule set

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have some trouble for mod-rewrite ruleset on my linux + Apache 2.x webserver.

Product PID has CG000XXXX format.

I want to call PID with shorten URL.
If i access with `www.DOM.com/?1234` call `www.DOM.com//product/detail.jsp?pid=BG0001234`

I applied following on my httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)$ /product/detail.jsp?pid=BG000$1 [NC,L]
```

It work.. but call wrong PID.

Please help... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you do say that Product PID has CG... format, but your query strings use BG...

Answer (score 0):

The rules are ok. Enable debugging on mod_rewrite and look what is happening when you access the url. I presume is a problem between Apache and your java application server.

```
RewriteLogLevel 3 
RewriteLog "/TMP/rewrite.log"
```